# Pressing a button to increment a variable which changes what values are printed to screen..?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, class, user-interface

My question is a little bit vague I know but it's a little difficult to explain...

Basically I have an event button with i++ which has already been declared:

```
    public void nextCardButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i++;
    }
```

I then have an array with various values, heres an example of a few values:

```
        myCard[0] = new Card("Vodka", 5, 6, 4, 0);
        myCard[1] = new Card("Gin", 7, 8, 3, 0);
```

This then gets split into two different players hands.

I then have my values outputting into labels in my windows form application:

```
        label1.Text = player1[i].cardName;
        percentageLabel1.Text = player1[i].cardPercentage.ToString();
        qualityLabel2.Text = player1[i].cardQuality.ToString();
        quantityLabel2.Text = player1[i].cardQuantity.ToString();
        tasteLabel2.Text = player1[i].cardTaste.ToString();
```

as you can see 'i' is responsible for changing which values are outputted...

My question is. How do I increment 'i' so that it changes my values in the labels?? My code is in

```
public void topTrumps_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

and my button click is

```
public void nextCardButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Sorry if this is a little vague but I wasn't sure how else to ask!

Comment: Yes, your question is vague. What values in what labels? Also, `i` is a horrendous name for what seems like a member variable to a class. Descriptive names are your friend :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, what you want is (roughly) this:

```
int i = 0;
public void nextCardButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i++;

    label1.Text = player1[i].cardName;
    percentageLabel1.Text = player1[i].cardPercentage.ToString();
    qualityLabel2.Text = player1[i].cardQuality.ToString();
    quantityLabel2.Text = player1[i].cardQuantity.ToString();
    tasteLabel2.Text = player1[i].cardTaste.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for! Seems so simple when its put in front of you! :P 
Now I just need to work out how to compare the card values with other ones and I'm done! :L

Comment: @Nolnar What do you mean accept the answer? Sorry very new to this :p

Comment: There's a check mark next to answers, click that (turning it green) to "accept" an answer as the one you feel answers your question.